# Spark : setNumClasses() for a subset of labels for Multiclass LogisticRegressionModel

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have a database with ids (labels) that range from 1 to 1040. I am using the Multiclass Logistic Regression for predciting the id. Now if I want to train only a subset of labels, let's say from 800 to 810. I get an error when I set setNumClasses(11) - for 11 classes. I must always set this method to the Max value of classes, which is 1040. That way the training model will train for all labels from 0 to 1040, and that is very expensive and uses a lot of resources.

Am I understaning this right? How can I train my model only for a subset of labels with giving the setNumClasses(count_of_classes).

```
final LogisticRegressionModel model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
            .setNumClasses(811).run(train.rdd());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments of previews answer I found the 2nd last comment is the main query. If you set setNumClasses(23) means: in the train set all the classes should be in the range of (0 to 22). Check the ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.html#setNumClasses(int))). It is written as:

> :: Experimental :: Set the number of possible outcomes for k classes classification problem in Multinomial Logistic Regression. By default, it is binary logistic regression so k will be set to 2.

That means, for binary logistic regression, binary values/classes are (0 and 1), so setNumClasses(2), is the default.

In the train set if you have other classes like 2,3,4, for binary classification it will not work.

Proposed Solution: if you have train set or subset contains 790 - 801 and 900 - 910 classes, then normalise or transform your data to (0 to 22) and put 23 as setNumClasses(23).

Comment: what do you mean by normalize? changing existing labels isn't a good idea, since it was already labeled like this. If by normalize you mean "take only records with those labels for training" then that's what my answer is proposing... Also you don't have to normalize them to a range `(0,k)`, a range `(n,n+k)` also works...

Comment: In your last comment, you said, "if in all the rows in the rdd AFTER your filter you will have only 21 classes (between 790 and 801 and between 900 and 910) then you should set the number of classes to 21". 
According to this you said you can set 21 as numClasses. Does this method work for 21 even you have labels in the train set between 790 and 801 and 900 to 910? I think you will get that error again. Am I right?

Comment: So, by normalise or transform I meant, Some how you have to label the subset of train set from 0 to K-1, for getting rid of that error. But you have to make sure that you get back the original labels after prediction.

Comment: No, it will work. It doesn't have to be in range `(0,21)`, it can be in ranges `(790,801) and (900,910)` as long as there's 21 distinct values

Comment: Can you please explain how it is possible? I can refer you in the docs here:
https://github.com/kaysar07cuet/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala

. If you check you will find a comments like this:
 * Train a classification model for Binary Logistic Regression
 * NOTE: Labels used in Logistic Regression should be {0, 1, ..., k - 1}
 * for k classes multi-label classification problem.
 * Using [[LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS]] is recommended over this.
 */"

Comment: Good catch, you are right! I must have checked some other source code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it like this, you are supplying a set of training data and it probably fails somewhere in the gradient descent method in Spark (not sure since you haven't provided the error message).

Also how is Spark supposed to figure out for which 800 labels should it train the model?

What you should do is to filter out only the rows in the RDD with the labels for which you want to train the model. For instance lets say your labels are values from 0 to 1040 and you only want to train for labels 0 to 800 you can do:

```
val actualTrainingRDD = train.filter( _.label < 801 )
final LogisticRegressionModel model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
        .setNumClasses(801).run(train.rdd());
```

@Edit: yes it's of course possible to choose a different set of labels, that was just an example, simply change the filter method to:

```
train.filter( row => (row.label >= 790 && row.label < 801) )
```

This is Scala, Java closures use `->`, right?

Comment: This was the Error when i passed MAX as 386.
ERROR DataValidators: Classification labels should be in {0 to 385}. Found 676 invalid labels. 
I want to filter the id's per User. Let's say i have many users with the same name and different ids. It doesn't make sense to me, that i must train "a thousand if rows" in order to predict a class (id) that lies in range 900 - 910.

Comment: To your example: I don't want to train from 0 - 800, but from 790 to 800. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sparkan yes but how is Spark (or to be more precise the underlying algorithms) know that you only want to use that model for labels 900-910 is you pass 11 as the number of classes? Yes just change the filter closure...

Comment: Yes I want to be able to extract these classes from DB so that I can  train the algorithm with them and set setNumClasses() to 11. 
I hope I can solve it with the filter closure. Thanks for this possible solution @Mateusz , and i will keep this post updated about my progress.

Comment: Hi again @Mateusz, what if the same User is having ids between two ranges? something like 790 - 801 AND 900 - 910? Is it also possible with filter?

Comment: @Sparkan you can put whatever filtering logic inside `filter` you want. Even if it's supposed to be within a set i.e. `1,3,6,7,11` you can create that set and use it inside your filter function like `train.filter( row => logic(row) )` where `logic` would be your function checking if a row with that label should be accepted or not

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz I appreciate it. But please bare with me for this last question: in case I do this `train.filter( row => logic(row) )` and I know that   for `790 - 801` and `900 - 910`  I have only `23` Classes (or could be less), would then the `setNumClasses()` be set to `23` or to `911`? And if i set to `911`, would it train for `911` classes? Sorry for this inconvenience, but I found no proper Documentation on this.

Comment: @Sparkan no problem, if in all the rows in the rdd AFTER your filter you will have only 21 classes (between 790 and 801 and between 900 and 910) then you should set the number of classes to 21.